# Can I make a buffer from two different weak acids or bases?

Tags: acid-base

Can I make a buffer using two different acids/bases? For example, adding 1 mole of acetic acid and 1 mole of ammonia?

The only information I can ever find is that I can make a buffer using *only* an acid (or base) and its *conjugate base* (or conjugate acid). So, carbonic acid and carbonate, $\ce{H2CO3}$ and $\ce{HCO3-}$.

Why do I need a conjugate acid-base pair and not two random weak acid-base pairs to make a buffer?

Comment: In your specific case, a combination of acetic acid $\ce{HC2H3O2}$ and ammonium $\ce{NH4+}$ would not work, since both species are acids.

Comment: @BenNorris you, sir, are a pedant. I think Nova meant ammonia NH3. Not everyone here is a native English speaker.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, having multiple weak acids and/or bases having different pKa values would give buffering capacity in more than one pH range, or over a greater pK range.

There is a term "[universal buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britton-Robinson_buffer)" which refers to a buffer having multiple pKas spaced thoughout the pH ~2-12 range to give some buffering capacity over the enter pH range.

As explained in [A Neutral Buffered Standard for Hydrogen Ion Work and Accurate
Titrations Which Can be Prepared in One Minute](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01344a025) J. Am. Chem. Soc., 1932, 54, pp 1911–1912, ammonium aceate has the property that if it is added to pure water it produces a buffered solution of pH 7.00, accurate to a hundreth of a pH unit.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can, but it depends on the way you prepare the buffer.

*A buffer solution is prepared by mixing a weak acid (or base) with a strong salt of that acid*

For example you can prepare the following buffer in two ways:

$\ce{HOAc + NaOAc}$

**1:**
Mixing directly a solution of the salt with the acid

**2:**
Adding (let's say dropwise) a solution of $\ce{NaOH}$ to the acid. In this case $\ce{NaOAc}$ will be formed *in situ*.

#### What you cannot do!

Prepare a buffer by mixing $\ce{HOAc}$ with $\ce{NaCl}$ for example

On the other hand you can mix two different buffers to get a new one with a different pH range like in the case of universal buffers.

Comment: The $\ce{OAc}$ shorthand is typically used with $\ce{O}$ preceeding the $\ce{Ac}$, unless the connection continues to the right, in which case $\ce{AcONa}$ would be preferred.

Comment: Please refrain from readding clutter once it has been edited out.

Comment: @Jan I don't see why I can't include that line. Any explanation?

Comment: In short: the [help centre](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) which includes a note about ‘taglines’. And *hope this helps* is one of the most generic taglines out there. It does not much to answer the question and is thus perceived as noise and clutter. [Check out this tongue-in-cheek meta post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/2873) and a [similar but more earnest meta-post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/2912).

Comment: Of course it doesn't answer anything, I agree, it was just to be friendly. That's why it is at the end of the answer, to separate it from the rest of the content I'm aware that it's irrelevant and probably unnecessary, but is not disturbing anything there. Also thanks for the other corrections my native language is spanish and I'm triying to do my best.

Comment: @Marange Hi.  Thanks for offering the answer.  Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts as to why someone was trying to be helpful and remove it.  I'm going to leave the tagline in the post for now, but know that this behavior is discouraged for the reasons outlined in that post.  Thanks and welcome!

Comment: @ jonsca ♦ Ok I get it and removed it, no problems with it.